# Belarc Advisor sort of program on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a program that can list the installed softwares, packages and configurations files of the installed software on an Ubuntu system. On Windows there is a program called Belarc Advisor that makes a complete list of installed software together with their corresponding license keys and updates. Considering a fresh reinstall I need such functionality.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg --get-selections`?

Comment: @Jobin I will try it thanks for the suggestion.